# Trying to access a variable outside constructor scope in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

This is part of my service layer in an Angular project. Why does `console.log` give me undefined for `count`? I can only access the value in a subscriber function. I want use the count in BehaviorSubject; how can I access it there?

```
export class DataService {

    public count;
    private baskets;

    constructor(private _store: StoreService) {
            this._store.reviewBasketProduct().subscribe(data => {
            this.baskets = data;
            //console.log(data.len)
            this.count =  this.baskets.length;
        })

        console.log('aa' + this.count)
    }

    private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.count);
    currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write console inside the subscribe, because console executes before reviewBasketProduct subscribe.

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class DataService implements OnInit {

    public count;
    private baskets;
    private messageSource;

    constructor(private _store: StoreService) {
        this._store.reviewBasketProduct().subscribe(data => {
            this.baskets = data;
            //console.log(data.len)
            this.count = this.baskets.length;
            console.log('aa' + this.count);
        });
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageSource = new BehaviorSubject < number > (this.count);
        currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this let me update my question actually i want use count as a parameter for BehaviorSubject but it is undifined

Comment: don't call directly inside the class, use onInit lifecycle hook.

Comment: it  is my data  service